# Module isomorphism, simple modules, and quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm reading R.S. Pierce's *Associative Algebras*. While proving a preliminary lemma to Nakayema's Lemma, the following is mentioned:

Let $M$, $N$, be two $A$-modules where $N$ is a submodule of $M$ and $M/N$ is simple. Let $u\in M$, $u\notin N$. Then $uA+N=M$.

This must be really elementary but I can't see why. I'm assuming it's related to some isomoprhism theorems and probably Schur's lemma. Or maybe it follows directly from the definitions of simple modules or quotient rings? Anyway, I don't think the assumption $u\notin N$ is necessary.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sure it is necessary, take $A=M=k$ and $N=0$. Then if $u\in N$, i.e. $u=0$ then $uA+N=0\neq M=k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the isomorphism theorem for modules there is an inclusion-preserving bijection between the submodules of $M/N$ and the submodules of $M$ containing $N$. Thus, because $uA+N$ properly contains $N$ and $M/N$ is simple it has to be equal to $M$.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I'm missing something basic.